# Difference between junit-vintage-engine and junit-jupiter-engine?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

It's a two-fold question.

1. What is the difference between `junit-vintage-engine` and `junit-jupiter-engine`?
2. SpringBoot starter projects come with an exclusion for `junit-vintage-engine`. Is it to enforce the use of junit-jupiter-engine?

Below is the dependency of my SpringBoot project generated from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: From Spring Boot 2.4 onwards, junit-vintage-engine has been removed from spring-boot-starter-test. Thus no need to explicitly exclude it any longer. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`junit-vintage-engine` is used for running JUnit 4 tests; `junit-jupiter-engine` for JUnit 5 tests.

Presumably since you'll be writing only JUnit 5 tests for a new Spring Boot project, the vintage engine won't be needed, hence the default dependency exclusion in the POM.

**Reference:**

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide

Answer (score 7):

**Answer : 1.** Based on reading i found some difference like,

**junit-vintage-engine :**

- Used in Junit-4 Testing.
- Used to call core classes and annotations.
- 'Assert' which provide assertion methods for performing test.
- 'Assume' used to place assumptions.
- Use annotation like, @Ignore, @Before, etc...

**junit-jupiter-engine :**

- Used in Junit-5 Testing
- Provide some API which helpful to write test cases.
- 'Assertions' provides utility methods of assertion condition for testing.
- 'Assumptions' - utility method provide condition based on assumption.
- Change the bit of annotation name like, @Disable, @BeforeAll, @BeforeEach, etc...

**Answer : 2.** I'm also amazed they are still providing older vintage library probably there is some reason which i don't know till now but based on current usage we'll see that in next update.

Have a nice day!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

First question is also related with the version of JDK. To be able to use jupiter engine, you must have Java 8 or higher. For second question; since the vintage engine is for JUnit4 and JUnit4 is greater than 10 years old, it is not recommended to be used. As far as I know, it has not been updated along this time although java has been evolved so much. I think that is why spring initializers enforce the use of junit-jupiter-engine.