# InjectMocks object is null in Unit testing

Tags: java, junit, mockito

This is my first junit tests using Mockito. I'm facing the issue of NPE for the service that was used in @InjectMocks. I looked at the other solutions, but even after following them, it shows same. Here is my code.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class CustomerStatementServiceTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private BBServiceImpl bbService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);    

    }

/**
 *  This test is to verify SUCCESS response
 */

@Test
public void testSuccess() { 

    BBResponse response = bbService.processDetails(txs);
    assertEquals("SUCCESSFUL" ,response.getResult());
}
}
```

### BBServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class BBServiceImpl implements BBService {

final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BBServiceImpl.class);



public BBResponse process(List<Customer> customers) { 
  // My business logic goes here
}
}
```

### Pom.xml

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>




    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My "bbService" object is null here

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Is the test-class annotated with `@ExtendsWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`? Do you declare the mock? Are the mocks annotated with `@Mock`= Please post a [MRE].

Comment: @Turing85, yes it is annotated with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Comment: if you are using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) then you don't need MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

Comment: Also, share the code for BBServiceImpl.

Comment: There are no instance fields annotated with `@Mock`, thus there is nothing to inject.

Comment: @dassum, updated with service impl

Comment: try removing MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

Comment: I removed it and it still throws same.

Comment: Again, you have to add instance fields for the mocks and annotate them with `@Mock` in your test-class. --- On a sidenote: Rather than using a static `logger`-field, inject the logger to make it testable. (I created a [Kata](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/loggerunittestkata/src/master/) for exactly this case some time back).

Comment: @Turing85, so what exactly needs to be added? Can you pls update with the code

Comment: please check are there any class level attributes in BBServiceImpl class or any non-argument constructor has been used.

Comment: @Syed of course I can. My hourly wage is USD 250 (excluding taxes, of course).

Comment: @dassum, there are no class level attributes, there is only one method in it. Nothing more exists in that class

Comment: can you try with BBService bbService instead of BBServiceImpl bbService

Comment: Junit 4 or Junit 5 (check annotations used)

Comment: Junit 4, updated in the question

Comment: @dassum, tried with that too. Still same :(

Comment: jdk-version and vendor?

Comment: jdk 1.8 version.

Comment: Works fine for me (using a jdk 1.8 with the same dependencies). Consider adding the stacktrace.

Comment: @second, it points at the same line where bbService is used

Comment: So you say, I would still like to see a complete version of it. If you can add a [mre] that reproduces the error feel free to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208804/discussion-between-syed-and-second).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a discussion which provided additional informations, the answer can be summarized as a maven configuration problem between `junit4` and `junit5`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cts.rabo.CustomerStatementServiceTests.testSuccess(CustomerStatementServiceTests.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60) 
...
```

The stacktrace showed a clear usage of the `junit5` engine.

The pom also included the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

> Before Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter-test included junit4 dependency transitively. Spring Boot 2.2.0 onwards, Junit Jupiter is included instead.

And according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193282/difference-between-junit-vintage-engine-and-junit-jupiter-engine) the exclusion seems to prevent the execution.

Removing the exlusion solved the problem for me.

---

I recommend a switch to `junit5` if there are no apparent requirements to use `junit4`.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961057/how-to-use-mockito-with-junit5) for more infos on how to use `mockito` together with `junit5`.

Comment: It was the version of mockito core which was causing issue. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1604

Answer (score 2):

I think you misuse the `@InjectMocks` annotation

It makes sense if you have a real class (usually the one you want to test) that **has dependencies**, which are initialized with constructor injection or setter injection.

`BBServiceImpl` on the other hand has no real dependencies.

Now, you could create mocks for those dependencies manually and then create an instance of the class under test or let mockito identify the way to create the class and "inject" the mocks for you. You'll still want to create mocks by means of using `@Mock` annotation because you do want to specify expectations during the test.

Here is an example of how it should look like:

```
public interface BBService {
    int process(String s); // simplified but still illustrates the concept
}

public class BBServiceImpl implements BBService {
    //here is a dependency that should be mocked when we will test BBServiceImpl class

    private  SizeCalculator sizeCalculator;

    // I use constructor injection here
    public BBServiceImpl(SizeCalculator sizeCalculator) {
        this.sizeCalculator = sizeCalculator;
    }

    public int process(String s) {
        // here is a dependency invocation
        return sizeCalculator.calculateSize(s);
    }
}
```

As you see, the implementation has a real dependency that can be mocked during the test.

Now, this dependency looks like:

```
public interface SizeCalculator {
    int calculateSize(String s);
}

public class SizeCalculatorImpl implements SizeCalculator {
    public int calculateSize(String s) {
        return s.length();
    }
}
```

Ok, now lets create a test for the `BBServiceImpl`. We don't want to create a `SizeCalculatorImpl` and prefer to supply a mock for it and specify an expectation on the runtime generated proxy created out of the interface `SizeCalcluator`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoInjectMocksTest {

    // I need a reference on my mock because I'll specify expectations during the tests
    @Mock
    private SizeCalculator sizeCalculator;

    @InjectMocks
    private BBServiceImpl underTest;

    @Test
    public void testInjectMocks() {
        Mockito.when(sizeCalculator.calculateSize("hello")).thenReturn(5);

       int actual = underTest.process("hello");

        assertEquals(actual, 5);
    }
}
```

Note the line

```
@InjectMocks
private BBServiceImpl underTest;
```

Mockito will find the constructor and inject the mock

Of course in this case we could do it manually:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class SampleManualTest {
    @Mock
    private SizeCalculator sizeCalc;

    private BBServiceImpl underTest;
    @Before
    public void init() {
        this.underTest = new BBServiceImpl(sizeCalc);
    }
}
```

But think about the case where there are many dependencies in class `BBServiceImpl`, InjectMocks can be more convenient in this case + if the setter injection is used, this way can save explicit calls to the setters.